# Apply Two FontFamily in the same text

Tags: c#, string, text, fonts, class-library

I am using C# and VS2013 to build an a windows phone App and I am facing the following problem:

I have a long string which has few paragraph in 2 different languages, I want to apply different font family to the part of each language..
And all this text is going to be displayed inside one textbox.

I have the text defined inside a class library:

```
SubCatgs17[27] = new SubCategory(1728, 17, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \n\n الفقرة في النصوص اللغوية هي جزء من مقال \n\n Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam", "");
```

Is there anything that I can do to apply different font family to specific parts of text..

a friend suggested maybe I could add some sort of tags inside the text, and then I could write a code based on the start and end of those tags to change the fontfamily.
but i don't know about such possibilities...Any help?

Thank You